# Using Firebase and ionic.io platform authentication

Tags: ionic-framework, firebase, firebase-authentication

We are writing a mobile application using [Ionic **Framework**](http://ionicframework.com/) and [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/) for our data storage. Now we are looking into the new [Ionic **Platform**](http://ionic.io/platform) for easy deployment and easy push notifications features.

Now as we are going to use most of the **Ionic Platform** features, we would also like to use their authentication system, also because it makes sending push notifications to specific users easy from within our Ionic Platform dashboard and their API.

Now I am trying to figure out how to incorporate the [Ionic User Authentication](http://docs.ionic.io/docs/user-overview) with Firebase.

In short: **How can we link our Ionic users to our Firebase authentication and authorization**?

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, it looks like Ionic is providing a similar authentication services as Firebase does.
The point is, if you need to create [user based security](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/user-security.html) on the Firebase database, that is, limit data access based on the user identity, you will have to use the Firebase authentication.

In any case I don't see a scenario where you need both authentication systems together.

Comment: I only want users to be able to read my Firebase data when they are authenticated. So I might just use anonymous authentication in my app just to be able to authenticate in my Firebase?

Comment: It won't be anonymous. You will just rely on Firebase authentication instead of the ionic one. Whenever you need to check the user identity you will use something like `ref.getAuth()`